# Using variables in postgres rule

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

In postgres rules (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrule.html), is it possible to use variables? For example, if in the rule I do

```
CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS
    ON INSERT TO t1
    DO INSTEAD
        INSERT INTO t1 (id, a) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), new.a)
        INSERT INTO t4 (id) VALUES (??????)
```

Can I somehow set the value of `uuid_generate_v4()` in the first INSERT as a variable so that I can use it in the second INSERT? Or is there any way to get the generate id from the first INSERT so it can be used in the second?

Also I'm getting an error `infinite recursion detected in rules for relation`. Probably because the rule is for table t1 but it contains a statement to insert into t1. How can I make this work?

Comment: I would think you could probably use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) to select the uuid value and the reference it in the insert, though there are probably other ways. Also your recursion most likely comes from the fact that on every insert into `t1` you create a rule that performs an insert into `t1` triggering the rule again.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I'm getting an error infinite recursion detected in rules for
>   relation. Probably because the rule is for table t1 but it contains a
>   statement to insert into t1. How can I make this work

It cannot work.
See documentation: [39.4. Rules on INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-update.html)

> The query trees generated from rule actions are thrown into the
>   rewrite system again, and maybe more rules get applied resulting in
>   more or less query trees. **So a rule's actions must have either a
>   different command type or a different result relation than the rule
>   itself is on, otherwise this recursive process will end up in an
>   infinite loop.** (Recursive expansion of a rule will be detected and
>   reported as an error.)

In other words, in a rule `ON INSERT TO t1` you can't fire another `insert` to the same table `t1`, because this cause that the rule will be recursively fired again and again - and this will cause an error. 

You need use a trigger to this task.

Comment: Rule recursion aside, the line
     INSERT INTO t1 (id, a) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), new.a)
should be
     INSERT INTO t1 (id, a) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), new.a) returning id

to get the uuid_generate_v4 value